# How can I find helper methods to create html tags outside of views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im creating a seeds file, generating dummy posts with dummy html. Im using Faker gem to help with ipsum text but I also want to be able to add html tags (img tags in particular) without the need to hard code. Is there any helpers like those in actionview ie image_tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

`ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("image.png")`

Answer (score 0):

You can access all helpers from ActionController::Base.helpers

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("foo")
```

Comment: i think it should work you may need to provide the file extension